# How to scale by pair of columns together

Tags: r

I want to use the scale function but to do it on each pair of columns - To calculate the mean on pair of columns and not on each column.

In details:
This is my data for example:

| phone | phone1_X | phone2 | phone2_X | phone3 | phone3_X |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| 2 | 4 | 6 | 8 | 10 | 12 |

I want to use the scale function on each pair phone1+phone1_X, Phone2+Phone2_X etc..
Each pair has the same name "phone1" but the second column always contains an additional "_X" (a different condition in the experiment).

In the end, I wish to have the original table but in Z.scores (but as I mentioned before, the mean is calculated by pair of columns and not by one column)

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

There might be a more elegant way, but this is how I'd do it.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -phone) %>%
  group_by(phone, name = stringr::str_extract(name, 'phone[0-9]?')) %>%
  summarise(mean_value = mean(value), .groups = 'drop') %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = mean_value)

#> # A tibble: 2 × 4
#>   phone phone1 phone2 phone3
#>   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1     1      2    3.5    5.5
#> 2     2      4    7     11
```

Comment: Hey, i tried to do so but it didn't work. that's the error I got:Error in `chr_as_locations()`:
! Can't subset columns that don't exist.
x Column `phone` doesn't exist.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: @Rbeginner Make sure all variables are named exactly as described. If you provide your example data using `dput()` it will be easier to troubleshoot.